# Can I use socket() on frameworks/native/service on Android?

Tags: android, sockets, frameworks, native

I want to implement socket function in the Android `frameworks/native/service/surfaceFlinger` for sending screen information.

So, I made my source code about networking by using `socket()`, and inserted into the Android framework source tree.

However, it couldn't create socket descriptor.

It always returned `-1` and errno is `13`

So I added permission code like this:

```
// framework/frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/mynetwork.cpp
if (PermissionCache::checkCallingPermission("android.permission.INTERNET") < 0)
...
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

But still doesn't work.

Any body know about this issue? 
and know soution?

Thank you.

Comment: It maintains global errno. It means error number 13.

Comment: Ok. What does errno 13 mean?

Comment: @greenapps OK. It means permission denied. But I don't know what permission I need and how to grant. Thank you.